# UITableview scrolls automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I came across a strange problem when I use `UITableView`. As shown with the picture below:

[image]

The ContentView is added on the view which is the root view of the `UIViewController`, and the UITableview is added on the `contentView`. I set the background color of the tableview to be green. The problem is that the `tableView` scrolls automatically ---- so you can see the `backgroundColor`.

The delegate method "`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`" is really invoked.

I also find out that in three kind of situations this will not happen:

1. set IOS version to be lower than 7.0.
2. add the `tableview` directly on the view instead of the `contentView`.
3. actually, the `ViewController` you see in the pic is a rootViewController of a `NavigationController` . If I do not use `NavigationController`, this problem will not happen.

So, what is the reason and how to solve it?

you can download the code here : http://pan.baidu.com/s/1bnChfsF

Comment: u need the content view means cells are showing in yellow color

Comment: @Anbu.Karthikan I do not understand..... can you tell me in detail?

Comment: here I submit the updated answer, this one is fine or do u need any changes